# perl: replace a string with variable containing new lines (line breaks)

Tags: text-processing, perl

I want to make edits containing meta characters. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed one of solutions is via `perl` with `s\Q ... \E` (near end of accepted answer). It is mentioned it handles multi-liners, but:

```
echo 'a-b' > a.txt;from='-';to='\n';perl -s -0777 -pe 's/\Q$from\E/$to/' -- -from="$from" -to="$to" a.txt
a\nb
echo 'a-b' > a.txt;from='-';to='\n';perl -s -0777 -pe 's/\Q$from\E/\n/' -- -from="$from" -to="$to" a.txt
a
b
```

I can replace with line break only if I write it in `s` itself, via variable it does not work for some reason. I could not find an answer via web search. How to make it work with `\n` in variable?

P.S. Variables can be of arbitrary length and contain any meta characters, all of which to be used literally except one particular sequence of characters (e.g. `\n`) to be replaced with line breaks.

Comment: Is an answer written in Raku (formerly Perl6) acceptable?

Comment: @jubilatious1, not sure about acceptable, but I guess could be useful. Can it be installed with `Command 'raku' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install rakudo`? (does it look like Raku you talk about?)

Comment: Yes, you got it. Raku is the language, Rakudo is the most advanced compiler/interpreter: https://rakudo.org/downloads

Comment: @jubilatious1, BTW the problem is mostly solved now, see edit 2 (I plan to move it to answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way, the issue is not in `Perl`, but in the `shell`:

```
echo 'a-b' > a.txt
from='-'
to=$'\n' # <<< look at this
perl -s -0777 -pe 's/\Q$from\E/$to/' -- -from="$from" -to="$to" a.txt
```

#### Output

```
a
b
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad I have not included more context for the problem. Variables to be read from a file (see Edit 3). I've already tried `$'\n'` but when placed in a line in the file code in edit 3 does not work to replace them with line breaks. Maybe you can modify it a bit to work with `$'\n'?

Comment: Stop changing rules 3 times, it's not ChatGPT. Be precise, concise.

Comment: Well, first answer assumed if code works with variables of length 1 that should be fine. Yours assumption is not unreasonable, still AFAIK stackexchange best practice is to ask for specific issue (and giving easily reproducible example), not post whole program to be fixed. I have not thought initially that how variables are populated matters. I wrote thank you and upvoted your answer.

Comment: If you think I should accept your answer and post another question, I'm ready to do so.

Comment: Yes, you should do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out a way to do that in two steps by preprocessing variables with:

```
to="$(printf "%s" "${to}" | perl -pe 's/\Q\n\E/\n/g')"
```

Surprisingly that does not work for single symbol (new line) replacement, but works for longer strings:

```
echo 'a-b' > a.txt;from='-';to='\n';to="$(printf "%s" "${to}" | perl -p -e 's/\Q\n\E/\n/g')";perl -s -0777 -pe 's/\Q$from\E/$to/' -- -from="$from" -to="${to}" a.txt
ab
echo 'a-b' > a.txt;from='-';to='\nd';to="$(printf "%s" "${to}" | perl -p -e 's/\Q\n\E/\n/g')";perl -s -0777 -pe 's/\Q$from\E/$to/' -- -from="$from" -to="${to}" a.txt
a
db
```

For now I do have longer strings only, still why it fails for single symbol I'd like to know.

It's working when reading variable assignments from a file to, like that:

```
itext="${line}"
itext="$(printf "%s" "${itext}" | perl -p -e 's/\Q\n\E/\n/g')"
while read -r line; do
    otext="${line}"
    otext="$(printf "%s" "${itext}" | perl -p -e 's/\Q\n\E/\n/g')"
    perl -s -0777 -pi -e 's/\Q$itext\E/$otext/' -- -itext="${itext}" -otext="${otext}" "${file_to_edit}"
done < "${file_with_edits}"
```